# Django Dependent/Chained Dropdown/Combo List

Tags: python, django, django-models

Cascading not working.

When I select Supplier, Services is not working. Nothing is happening.
on form load, the "Services" is not empty even though the code is there
I am not sure if forms.py is really needed or not.I have been trying this for few days now

Models.py

```
class supplierMaster(models.Model):
# supplierId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name= models.CharField(max_length=25)
status = models.ForeignKey(statusMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.supplierName

class servicesMaster(models.Model):
# serviceId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
supplier= models.ForeignKey(supplierMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.ForeignKey(statusMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.serviceName

class milestonesTran(models.Model):
# milestoneid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
supplier= models.ForeignKey(supplierMaster,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               default=0)
service= models.ForeignKey(servicesMaster,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              default=0)
serviceDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
SERVICES_STATUS_CHOICES = [(3, 'Pending'), (4, 'Completed')]
servicestatus = models.IntegerField(choices=SERVICES_STATUS_CHOICES,
                                    default=3)
status = models.ForeignKey(statusMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Views.py

```
def add_maintenance(request):
    services = servicesMaster.objects.all()
    supplier = supplierMaster.objects.all()
    servicestatus = statusMaster.objects.filter(pk__in=[3, 4])
    status = statusMaster.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 2])

# print(supplier)

return render(
    request, 'maintenance_add.html', {
        'services': services,
        'suppliers': supplier,
        'servicestatus': servicestatus,
        'status': status
    })

def add_maintenance_save(request):
if request.method != "POST":
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Method Not Allowed</h2>")
else:
    servicedate = request.POST.get("serviceDate")
    servicename = request.POST.get("servicelist")
    suppliers = request.POST.get("supplierlist")
    servicestatus = request.POST.get("servicestatuslist")
    status = request.POST.get("status")


    try:
        milstone = milestonesTran(serviceDate=servicedate,
                                  service_id=servicename,
                                  supplier_id=suppliers,
                                  servicestatus=servicestatus,
                                  status_id=status)
        milstone.save()
        messages.success(request, "Maintenance Added Successfully")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/servicetracker/add/')

    except:

        messages.error(request, "Failed to Add Maintenance")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/servicetracker/add/')

def load_services(request):
supplier_id = request.GET.get('supplier')
services = servicesMaster.objects.filter(
    supplier_id=supplier_id).order_by('serviceName')
return render(request, 'services_dropdown_list_options.html',
              {'services': services})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import milestonesTran, servicesMaster
class milestonesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = milestonesTran
        fields = ('serviceDate', 'supplier', 'service', 'servicestatus',
              'status')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['serviceName'].queryset = servicesMaster.objects.none()
```

maintenance_add.html

```
{% extends 'base_servicetracker.html' %}
{% block page_title %}
Add New Maintenance
{% endblock page_title %}
{% block content %}
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-primary">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Add New Maintenance</h3>
              </div>
              <form role="form" id="milestonesForm" action="new/{% url 'add_maintenance_save' as add_maintenance_save  %}" method="post" data-services-url="{% url 'servicetracker:ajax_load_services' %}">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Maintenance Date </label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="serviceDate" placeholder="Enter Date">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Supplier</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="supplierlist">
                        {% for sup in suppliers %}                            
                          <option value="{{ sup.id }}">{{ sup.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Service</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="servicelist">
                        {% for ser in services %}                            
                          <option value="{{ ser.id }}">{{ ser.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Service Status</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="servicestatuslist">
                        {% for serst in servicestatus %}                            
                          <option value="{{ serst.statusId }}">{{ serst.statusName }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Status </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="status">
                        {% for st in status %}                            
                          <option value="{{ st.statusId }}">{{ st.statusName }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add New Maintenance</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
{% block custom__js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#id_supplier").change(function () {
          var url = $("#milestonesForm").attr("data-services-url");  
          var supplierId = $(this).val(); 
          console.log(supplierId);
      $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
      'supplier': supplierId       
    },
    success: function (data) {   
      $("#id_service").html(data);  
    }
  });

});
});
</script> 
{% endblock custom__js %}
```

services_dropdown_list_options.html

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for service in services %}
<option value="{{ service.pk }}">{{ service.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You don't have inputs/selects with ids `id_supplier` or `id_service` since you are rendering them manually. Add these ids to the manually rendered inputs/selects

Comment: I tried  <select class="form-control" name="supplierlist" id="id_supplier"> and <select class="form-control" name="servicelist"  id="id_service"> but still the same issue

Comment: Where is the `custom__js` block in your template? You may need to wrap your jQuery in `$(function() {<CODE>});` so that it is executed on page load (after the entire page and the selects have been rendered) https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: still nothing :(